# Which cmd can let maven use appointed log.properties

Tags: maven

I have got a way of like this:

```
mvn test > log/1.log
```

I want maven can read my log-config.properties, so i can control the log

Answer (score 0):

I think you can't really change it from the command line. Maven 3.1.x+ uses SLF4J Simple, it loads `simplelogger.properties` from the classpath. Maven adds `${maven.home}/conf/logging` to classpath to allow editing `${maven.home}/conf/logging/simplelogger.properties`.

As of now you can't change where SLF4J looks for its configuration file (only `simplelogger.properties` on the classpath).

You also can't add anything to the Maven classpath via `mvn` command.

So I think what you want is not possible without fiddling with your Maven installation:

- Either edit `${maven.home}/conf/logging/simplelogger.properties`
- Or change SLF4J binding used by Maven to, say `Log4J` or whatever and condigura the path to your specific logging configuration file via system property